# How can i solve `mix content type error` in googleMap

Tags: google-maps, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am using **google maps** and getting `mix content type error` i wanna update firebase protocol `https` to `http`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase Hosting is HTTPS-only, but Google Maps fully supports HTTPS as well. You should look through your code for any `http://` URLs and see if changing them to `https://` still works.